# Conversion of 3 Classes of Target variable to 2 Class varibale

Tags: classification

I have a data set with target variable as categorical. Total 3 classes are there. "Car", "Bus", "Train". If i want to predict whether the person takes car or not, It's binary classification problem for me. How can i change it to, if a variable value is "Car" then Yes else for any other values it is "No". I did write a function, but it's not giving me the desired result.

Transport <- ifelse(Transport == "Car", Yes, No)

Please help me out.

Comment: Put quotation marks on **Yes** and **No**, like Transport <- ifelse(Transport == "Car", "Yes", "No"). However, if you are working with a data.frame, you could use **dplyr** and better variable name for a more readable code, like df <- df %>% mutate(IsCar = ifelse(Transport == "car", "Yes", "No"))

Comment: Thanks. Will try that.